# I am having an error while uploading app on app store

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, app-store

I uploaded my app successfully but it was was decalred as invalid with following error

"
Dear developer,
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Smart AR Reader". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
Invalid File Name - Your package contains a file 'AR Reader .app/AR Reader ' with a name that contains leading or trailing whitespace characters.
Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary.
Regards,
The App Store team
"

I removed the white space from my project name after making changes my app passses the validation test succesfully but the distribution process is failed with the message as in the following screen shot

I am still getting the same error regaring white space

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rename the project name Under Targets?

Rename the project Name under Targets

clean the build and recompile for binary then submit it.

Comment: Yes i have tried all that stuff but its not working

it says apple web service is not successful and Invalid File Name - Your package contains a file 'AR Reader .app/AR Reader ' with a name that contains leading or trailing whitespace characters and package authentication failed

Answer (score 0):

[image: Cick Enter on the NEW SPACE]

After Rename Click Enter again you will see the popup as shown

[image: Rename it]

No you can see underproduct space is removed recompile it and upload the binary

[image]